# How to assign a value to a null query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a problem with a query in Oracle. I want to assign the value -1 if my query returns null and the ID value if in the table there is at least a value. This is my query

```
SELECT IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID
FROM (SELECT * FROM IAM_EXP_RESULT ORDER BY START_DATE  ASC)
WHERE RESULT = 0 AND ROWNUM = 1
```

The query above returns no rows because the table is empty. I want to create a variable to assign the value -1 in this case, or the IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID value in the case that at least a value exists.

Comment: Itt sounds like you are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` with a `CASE` statement? I'm not 100% clear though. Something seems odd with trying to generate rows from a table with no rows.

Comment: Try using coalesce: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617 Es. Select coalesce(IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID, -1) .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT` analytic function and `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
         IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID,
         CASE WHEN ct > 0 THEN -1 ELSE NULL END
       ) AS IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID
FROM   (
  SELECT IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID,
         RESULT,
         START_DATE,
         COUNT( your_value_column ) OVER () AS ct
  FROM   IAM_EXP_RESULT r
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -1, 0, NULL, 0 FROM DUAL
  ORDER  BY START_DATE ASC NULLS LAST
)
WHERE  RESULT = 0
AND    ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use aggregation for this purpose:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(IAM_EXP_RESULT_ID), -1)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM IAM_EXP_RESULT
      ORDER BY START_DATE  ASC
     )
WHERE RESULT = 0 AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

An aggregation query always returns one row, with `NULL` if no rows match  The `COALESCE()` replaces the value with what you want.

Note:  You might want the `RESULT = 0` in the subquery.

Comment: `MAX` will not aggregate anything as `ROWNUM = 1` will restrict it to a single row.

Comment: @MTO . . . Nope.  The `WHERE` is evaluated before the aggregation.  That simply results in no rows, and a `NULL` return value.  `HAVING rownum = 1` would be a different story.

Comment: The OP needs to clarify their question but we are talking about two different situations. They start by saying "I want to assign the value -1 if my query returns null if in the table there is at least a value" - if it returns zero rows their query doesn't return `NULL` so the one returned row must contain a `NULL` value which was what my comment was about. Yours is about their "I want to create a variable to assign the value -1 in this case" statement in the final paragraph which is a confusingly similar but slightly different requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This general example in addition to others will return value if table has no rows and you cannot use count(*) or other aggregate function:

```
SELECT data_length FROM all_tab_cols
  WHERE owner = 'YOU'
   AND table_name = 'EMP'
   AND column_name = 'ENAMES'
UNION ALL
 SELECT -1 FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT data_length FROM all_tab_cols
   WHERE owner = 'YOU'
     AND table_name = 'EMP'
     AND column_name = 'ENAMES'
  )
/
```

The result of above query is -1. The top portion may or may not return rows. If top portion returns rows then you get whatever it returns. If not then you get -1.